# Working of python Interpreter is little bit confusing

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

1st of all see the files i made. there is something in which i am confused, Its not about getting solution. It's about how python works.

this is the code which works fine:-

```
from kivy.support import install_twisted_reactor
install_twisted_reactor()
import dbm,pickle
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen,ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel

Builder.load_string('''
<Blackmailing>:
    Button:
        text: 'Send'
        on_press: app.msg()
        size_hint: (0.3, 1)
''')

class ChatClient(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.app.on_connect(self.transport)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.factory.app.on_message(data)


class ChatClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = ChatClient

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

class Blackmailing(Screen):

    def send_black(self):
        return PracticeApp().msg("hello")
class PracticeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        print('-- connecting to')
        reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8000,
                           ChatClientFactory(self))
        return Blackmailing()

    def msg(self):
        self.conn.write("hello")

    def on_connect(self, conn):
        print('-- connected')
        self.conn = conn

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PracticeApp().run()
```

In the above program as you can see on clicking button a function gets called msg(). In which self.conn attribute is there of another function of the same class.there is no problem this code works fine

And here is the similar(exact code with little change) and it doesn't work:-

```
from kivy.support import install_twisted_reactor
install_twisted_reactor()
import dbm,pickle
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen,ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel

Builder.load_string('''
<Blackmailing>:
    Button:
        text: 'Send'
        on_press: root.send_black()
        size_hint: (0.3, 1)
''')

class ChatClient(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.app.on_connect(self.transport)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.factory.app.on_message(data)


class ChatClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = ChatClient

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

class Blackmailing(Screen):

    def send_black(self):
        return PracticeApp().msg("hello")
class PracticeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        print('-- connecting to')
        reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8000,
                           ChatClientFactory(self))
        return Blackmailing()

    def msg(self,message):
        self.conn.write(message)

    def on_connect(self, conn):
        print('-- connected')
        self.conn = conn

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PracticeApp().run()
```

And here as u can see on clicking the button i called a root class which is send_black() and in that class's function which is send_black() i am calling the msg() of PracticeApp() class which i called directly in previous code.And in msg() function there is self.conn attribute of another function of same class,but this time an error is comming which says "no attribute named self.conn". Why so?

Sorry if i was unable to make you understand the problem. But i would like to have the proper reason for this. I will be very thankfull to the person who can tell me the correct reason. Thankyou

Comment: what's the diff?  Can you demonstrate this without using kivy, dbm and pickle? My first reaction is "the error message just told you" if it never connected then on_connect never got called, so self.conn was never set, and therefore does not exist.

Comment: Maybe you ran the first one but it never disconnected, so when you run the second it can't connect?  You may need to check for errors on functions like connectTCP. Usually python stuff throws exceptions, but check the docs.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Thanx for the reply. As u said imay be its never connected and function never called and self.conn never existed, I tried it it and checked it many times with diff. diff. strategies all time but it never worked